# Apache 2.2, Mac mini, Sierra, Server 5.2

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zQVt.jpg)I realise this is a all vintage stuff, but I need to have this server up and running for 6 more months. The mac server interface shows that Apache is up and running, but it is not serving any page. As the server other services are doing well I suspect it is related to Apache. Hence my question on this forum.

The issue started when I deleted one certificate. The error log (under /var/log/apache2/service_proxy_error.log) shows this line :

[... Syntax error on line 215 of /Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/certificates/example.domain.com.76EA32A02BEFC81EFC4B31FA08C84A262AF93464.cert.pem' does not exist or is empty …])

(nb: example.domain.com replaces the real name)

When I look at the that file at line 215 it shows this : SSLCertificateFile "/etc/certificates/${CERT_ID}.cert.pem"

those values seem come from a file called servermgr_web_apache2_config under /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2

That entry on that file  apache_serviceproxy.conf is

```
    <dict>
        <key>SSLPassPhrase</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Port</key>
            <string>443</string>
            <key>SSLCertificateKeyFile</key>
            <string>/etc/certificates/example.domain.com.76EA32A02BEFC81EFC4B31FA08C84A262AF93464.key.pem</string>
            <key>ServerName</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>enabled</key>
            <true/>
            <key>mstCertificateIdentifier</key>
            <string>SHA-256:3d7b608faa3c8936d5015652ae1c9b203eb40af444cc3444862201aa821d4a6d:"example.domain.com"</string>
            <key>sslCertificateIdentifier</key>
            <string>example.domain.com.76EA32A02BEFC81EFC4B31FA08C84A262AF93464</string>
        </dict>
        <key>_id_</key>
        <string>*:443_</string>
    </dict>
```

But as that certificate is no more I wonder why this entry is there and if that is not the reason why Apache does not delivers the pages.

This issue is beyond me. I need help to solve this issue on that server. Any help is welcome (replacing that server for now is not an option due to legacy issue on one project.)

Any idea? Thank you !

**ps1:** when connectin to the URL any browse displays this :
[...Unable to connect

An error occurred during a connection to [www.xxx.com](http://www.xxx.com).

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
```

... ]

note that it reverts automatically to a https, but right now there is no https.

**ps 2:** Under Certificates is see a list of certificates [4m 2 self signed, 2 from Rapidssl]m . Above that I see a line saying Secure services using [one of the self-signed] ;

Comment: "The mac server interface shows that Apache is up and running, but it is not serving any page." What does that mean? Can you add a Server app screenshot of what you are referring to? Also please explain and/or post a screenshot of what you see in the Server app under "Certificates".

Comment: a Mac mini isn't a business environment and therefor e not on topic

Comment: Hi not2savvy, see edited version of op, incl. screenshot

Comment: Apache 2.2 is End Of Life. It has been EOL for [four years](https://httpd.apache.org/).